# Not all constituents of type 'number | function' are callable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider a simple function like this:

```js
export const add = (num?: number) => {
    const adder = (n: number) => {
        if (!n) {
            return num;
        }
        num = (num && num + n) || n;
        return adder;
    };

    return adder;
};
```

Example usage:

```js
const result = add(1)(2)(3)() // => 6
```

When called, `add` will either return next function that takes another number, or a final sum if no number is passed.

This would work as expected in plain js, however for typescript this will cause an error:

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type 'number | ((n?: number | undefined) => (x?: number | undefined) => number | ...)' are callable.
> Type 'number' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

This is because TS cannot determine if the next iteration returns a function or a number.

### Question:

How to type this function correctly, so that TS does not throw an Error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to describe the call signature of `add()` so that callers will see the desired behavior.  Unfortunately the TypeScript compiler will not be able to *verify* that the implementation of `add()` satisfies this call signature; it would need to be smarter about [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) implementations or the behavior of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to do so.  This means we'll need at least one [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or similar type-loosening technique to suppress compiler errors.

Anyway, let's say that `add` is a function of a type I'll call `Adder`:

```
interface Adder {
  (n: number): Adder;
  (n?: undefined): number
}
```

An `Adder` is an overloaded function with two call signatures; either you call it with a `number` in which case another `Adder` is returned, or you call it with no arguments (or I guess an `undefined` one) in which case you get a `number`.  Now we can assert that `add` is an `Adder`:

```
const add = ((num?: number) => {
    const adder = (n: number) => {
        if (!n) {
            return num;
        }
        num = (num && num + n) || n;
        return adder;
    };

    return adder;
}) as Adder; // <-- assertion
```

And then things behave as expected:

```
const result = add(1)(2)(3)() // no error now

console.log(result); // 6
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN3WQbwFDKHIAUIAXMiAK4C2ARtAJQUZZQDcBRpA-BVSCwxQEdM0q0GUPAF88eBAHsQAZzDI4mZAF4SvCtXpMdAPlxdCAGwjrECHZWQAfJ8gAMnIsig2qUECQAHnwSRlCMpuZeXsAwQTraugJCImJR0Rk+YH4Bdp4ZyHIFGgj2unbIANTIgfmZvv4amHWFnDIRcCpomNDsyAD0-cgAPAC0oxoqKtBgwMrySqrqPipUlurlmMQAjIzEAEx7AMx7EYORAGwLyiqK1gB0looA5sQra2CMQA)

Comment: Yeah every odd call with return the function, not a value !

Comment: Yes, you are right, the implementation is off, I will fix that in a moment.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, this works! And sorry for the imlpementation issue, already fixed it. Can you update your answer to match the question? (so as to not confuse others who will see this)

Comment: Already done ...